# Image moving behind the div

Tags: html, css, image

Ok, so I have a problem with my website I'm creating. I have 3 main divs: a **header**, **a top bar**, just below de header, and a **main div**, just below de top bar.

In my main div, I put an image of a car and made it moving to the top with java script. But, in its way to the top of the page, I jave my **header** and my **top bar** divs, and the image moving up, is moving IN FRONT OF the divs, so the divs are behind the image. I've already tried almost everything with the positions and index-z, but i couldn't figure it out, how to put the image behind the divs on when it's going up. I hope you understood and please help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2nvC.png
this is the part from the web page with the car. I just want it go behind those divs when it's going up.

This is the **image of the car**:

```
<img src="images/top_main_image.png" id="car" style="position:relative;bottom:5px;margin-left:41.8%;margin-top:50px;">
```

This is **the header div and the top bar**:

```
div.header
{
    width:auto;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#333333;
    float:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: auto; 
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

div.top_bar
{
    width:auto;
    height:110px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    float:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: auto; 
    posotion:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this CSS for the image. I changed the position from relative to absolute and I added z-index. You could try the whole example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/khkvt42r/).

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 41.8%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  z-index: -1
```